# How to deploy Java service class (jar files) without restart wildfly server

Tags: wildfly, activiti, hotswap, hotswapagent

I would like to know whether it's possible to deploy customized Java service class to activiti without restart the application server (wildfly in my case).

Currently, I have to put the jar to classes folder and then restart the whole server. I have already tried HotSwapAgent but it seems not work.

Comment: Did you try to redeploy your complete application ?

Comment: It should work. But I want to know if there's a method like osgi which is used by WSO2 Process Server that could deploy process definitions together with external java class on runtime without restart anything.

Comment: Ideally, the process logic implemented in Java should be specific to a given process version. If you have to change those classes too often in production, then this is a sign that those classes should be deployed as a standalone rest/soap/ejb service, decoupling the lifecycle of the process and its instances from the services. REST/SOAP are fine if you can stand for the extra overhead. Otherwise, EJBs are the way to go, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

We are addressing this problem in Activiti Cloud: https://activiti.gitbooks.io/activiti-7-developers-guide/content/
But as Philippe mention, if your class is code that changes quite often, you should think about having a separate service for it.